# How can I add a thick bottom border to a range of rows when the cell value changes?

Tags: excel, vba, border

I have code that will insert a blank row when a cell value changes.

How can I modify this to instead add a thick bottom border?  The border would go from column `A` to column `AB` every time the value in column `B` changes

```
Sub InsertRows()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rowPtr As Long

lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For rowPtr = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("B" & rowPtr)) Then
        If Range("B" & rowPtr) <> Range("B" & rowPtr - 1) Then
            Range("B" & rowPtr).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess this is Excel. It looks more like a VBA macro than vb.net code.

Comment: It is Excel VB.

Comment: Excel VB is probably VBA. Where are you writting the code? In Visual Studio or Excel?

Comment: In Excel.  It executes as a macro.  Just not sure how to write that once the value in column B changes to add a border from column A to column AB in the row where the value has changed in column B

Comment: You will get more help with different tags. vb.net is only for code usually written in Visual Studio in the vb.net language which is different from VBA.

Comment: I thought my tags show excel-vba and border

Comment: I just edited them. They originally showed VB.net.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Range("B" & rowPtr).Select
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
```

Comment: It selects only Column B where the value changes.  How would I change it to border from A to AB when the the value in B changes?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part.  Make the Range function: Range("A" & rowPtr & ":AB" & rowPtr).Select

Answer (score 0):

Basically, replace the `Range("B" & rowPtr).EntireRow.Insert` code with code to add a border!

Your code refactored, plus a few other tweeks

```
Sub BorderRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rowPtr As Long
    Dim columnsToBorder As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    columnsToBorder = 28
    With ws
        lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'Optional, clear existing borders
        With .UsedRange.Resize(, columnsToBorder)
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
        End With

        For rowPtr = 2 To lastRow
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(rowPtr, 2)) Then
                If .Cells(rowPtr, 2).Value <> .Cells(rowPtr - 1, 2).Value Then
                    With .Cells(rowPtr, 1).Resize(1, columnsToBorder).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .Weight = xlThick
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next

        'Optional, add borber to last row
        With .Cells(lastRow, 1).Resize(1, columnsToBorder).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With

    End With
End Sub
```